# How to apply a common style and theme to our project?

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to use the same Header in my project . I want to display two image buttons and one textview in the header part. i want to use the same header part to all the screens of my project but want to change the text of textview according to my screen. please anyone help me how can i apply the styles and theme so that i am able to use the same header in my project and change the textview according to the project screen.

Comment: what sort of theme you need

Comment: i want to add custom theme of my own. please tell me how can i add the theme of my own.?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>


    </style>
</resources>
```

more [info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) or try [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: nops can u explain why to take parent as @android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"> in custom styles

Comment: @DeepanshiUpadhyay you got your answer